# bx slider: How to continue auto sliding after clicking in default bx pager?

Tags: jquery, navigation, bxslider

I want to continue the autosliding after clicking on a bx pager item.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal', //mode: 'fade',            
        speed: 500,
        auto: true,
        infiniteLoop: true,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        useCSS: false
    });

    $(".bx-pager-link").click(function () {
        console.log('bla');            
        slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
        slider.stopAuto();
        slider.startAuto();
        //slider.stopShow();
        //slider.startShow();
    });
});
```

The uncommented `stopShow()` and `startShow(`) function doesn't work at all. `startAuto()` continues the slideshow but the bx pager navigation is frozen. The active dot stays active even if new slide appears. How to solve that?

Comment: Why are you invoking .bxSlider() function again?

Comment: I tried it with var slider =$('.bxslider').bxSlider({...}); first but I think there was an error when I called slider.startAuto(). But I'm not sure anymore...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal', //mode: 'fade',            
        speed: 500,
        auto: true,
        infiniteLoop: true,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        useCSS: false
    });

    $(".bx-pager-link").click(function () {
        console.log('bla');            
        slider.stopAuto();
        slider.startAuto();
    });
});
```

Or you can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal', //mode: 'fade',            
        speed: 500,
        auto: true,
        infiniteLoop: true,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        useCSS: false
    });

    $('.bx-pager-item a').click(function(e){
        var i = $(this).index();
        slider.goToSlide(i);
        slider.stopAuto();
        restart=setTimeout(function(){
            slider.startAuto();
            },500);

        return false;
    });
});
```

The second is works for me.

Comment: thx! That was a big help! But it doesn't work with your i variable. Has to be: var i = $(this).attr("data-slide-index"); ;)

Answer (score 8):

Following code working fine in site. Please try it :

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    pager: false,
    autoHover: true,
    autoControls: true,
    onSlideAfter: function() {
        slider.stopAuto();
        slider.startAuto();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    controls: false,
    onSliderLoad: function () {
        $('.bx-pager-link').click(function () {
            var i = $(this).data('slide-index');
            slider.goToSlide(i);
            slider.stopAuto();
            slider.startAuto();
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var clickNextBind = function(e){
            // if auto show is running, stop it
            if (slider.settings.auto) el.stopAuto(); **<--- You must Delete this row.**
            el.goToNextSlide();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
```

Comment: Thx! Didn't try it yet but looks logical to me :)

Comment: Not only that row but also the other 2 occurrences of that line. Practically you can search for the comment : `// if auto show is running, stop it` to find them.

Answer (score 1):

For improving the answer, this worked for me on both mobile when you click if you are in a browser or if you swipe when you are on the phone, is clean, short and simple:

```
var slider = $('.slider');
    slider.bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true,
        onSlideAfter: function() {
            slider.startAuto()
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the solutions above, but no luck and I'm using the latest version 4.1.2

In Jquery.bxslider.js add  "el.startAuto();"

```
/**
 * Click next binding
 *
 * @param e (event)
 *  - DOM event object
 */
var clickNextBind = function(e){
    // if auto show is running, stop it
    if (slider.settings.auto) el.stopAuto(); 
    el.goToNextSlide();
    e.preventDefault();
     el.startAuto();
}

/**
 * Click prev binding
 *
 * @param e (event)
 *  - DOM event object
 */
var clickPrevBind = function(e){
    // if auto show is running, stop it
    if (slider.settings.auto) el.stopAuto();
    el.goToPrevSlide();
    e.preventDefault();
     el.startAuto();
}
```

Comment: Although I don't like modifying the libraries core files itself, your solution is the only solution worked for me!

Comment: @Khaled Mahmoud I tried everything all over Internet and I found this somewhere else, this need to be fixed in next version.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
$('.bx-pager-item a').click(function(e){
    //blah
});
```

set the click function to point directly to the bx-prev and bx-next. This one works better for me.

```
$('.bx-prev, .bx-next').click(function(e){
    //blah
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working good ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
         video: true,
          useCSS: false,
          });

           $(".bx-controls-direction").click(function () {
            console.log('bla');            
            slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
            slider.stopVideo();
            slider.startVideo();
            //slider.stopShow();
            //slider.startShow();
        });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code :

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

$('.bx-pager-link').click(function () {
    var i = $(this).attr('data-slide-index');
    slider.goToSlide(i);
    slider.stopAuto();
    slider.startAuto();
    return false;
});
```

Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score -1):

In `jquery.bxslider.min.js`, search for and hide

```
r.stopAuto= function(t) {

//o.interval && (clearInterval(o.interval), o.interval = null, o.settings.autoControls && // 1 != t //&& A("start"))
 },
```