# Auto sliding not working after click next slider button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jquery plugin for testimonial. When i click next slider button it will stop auto sliding. How can i solve that??

here my js code

```
$('.testimonials-slider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 800,
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 1,
            slideMargin: 32,
            auto: true,
            autoControls: true
          });
```

here my external js

[External Js](http://gacglobal.net/site/slider/js/jquery.bxslider.js)

[Live Demo](http://gacglobal.net/site/slider/)

Comment: its working fine i think .. whats the issue ?

Comment: click on next or previous arrow. after that it will not slide automatically

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518566/bx-slider-how-to-continue-auto-sliding-after-clicking-in-default-bx-pager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var slider = $('.testimonials-slider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 800,
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 1,
            slideMargin: 32,
            auto: true,
            autoControls: true
          });

   $('.bx-prev, .bx-next').click(function(e){
    slider.stopAuto();
    setTimeout(function(){
           slider.startAuto();
     },300);

    return false;
  });
});
```